# Understanding java generics

Tags: java, generics

In the following assignment, I need to use `List<? extends Number>`:

```
List<? extends Number> list = Arrays.asList(1.2, 3, 4.5);
```

While `Arrays.asList(1.2, 3, 4.3)` has the type `List<Number & Comparable<?>>`, and considering `List` genertic type in java is invariant, and with wildcard `?`, it can be made into contravariant. So if it contravariant, and `Number & Comparable<?>` is subtype of `Number`, and then `List<Number & Comparable<?>>` is the supertype of `List<? extends Number>`. Then this is not correct, since it is assigning the supertype to a subtype (downcasting)!

Where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: `Comparable` is an *interface*. There is no multiple inheritance in Java.

Comment: so? sorry that i don't see how it is related

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work.  If you turn on compiler warnings you will see the compiler is protesting that an unchecked conversion is being performed.  The compiler is telling you it's unable to verify at compile-time that the cast you've inferred is correct.

Comment: what does not work?In my `intellij`, I don't see any warning/error.

Comment: Works fine in Java 7, no warnings with `-Xlint:all`

Comment: Java 7 adds @SafeVarArgs that suppresses it apparently.

Comment: I'm not using that annotation, and there's no warnings. Compiling with 1.6.0_43 also issues no warnings using `-Xlint:all`